# How to replace a column with string only containing the lemmas of all the tokens?

Tags: python, pandas, string, nlp, lemmatization

I have a column name “Text_Tweet” within a dataframe where each row contains a tweet.

How can I replace each row of tweet with string only containing the lemmas of each?

Comment: That's a bit broad question without providing any input or detail...

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in utility in `nltk` package which allows us to lemmatize words in the easiest way ever. In the end, we would be alone with something like that:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import pandas as pd 
your_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({
    'Text_Tweet':['rocks corpora', 'corpora rocks']
})
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
your_dataframe['Processed_Tweet'] = your_dataframe['Text_Tweet'].apply(lambda item:' '.join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in item.split()]))
your_dataframe
```

output:

```
      Text_Tweet Processed_Tweet
0  rocks corpora     rock corpus
1  corpora rocks     corpus rock
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
import nltk
w_tokenizer = nltk.tokenize.WhitespaceTokenizer()
lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()

def lemmatize_text(text):
    return [lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in w_tokenizer.tokenize(text)]

#example of datasets
df = pd.DataFrame(['I am a boy', 
                   'He likes these books', 
                   'There were four columns'], columns=['Text_Tweet'])

df['lemm'] = df.Text_Tweet.apply(lemmatize_text)
```